# DocuSign Sugarcrm Module Integration giving internal server 500 error

Tags: sugarcrm, docusignapi

I am using this module (http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/docusignsugar-1/) for Sugarcrm and Docusign integration. After much effort I was able to connect both systems and its working however, its showing an internal server error when it sends the document from docusign. Please see the attached image for reference

One thing to note here is that the docusign module is sending the document with signature however it is showing an internal server error 500 at the last step after sending.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What version of SugarCRM are you using?

Comment: I am using sugarCRM 6.3, the error is showing on the detail view of Accounts module in SugarCRM

Comment: Yes Community Edition